# I need to remove the zeros, java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

i have this source code: (it's my homework). Create a program that will convert numbers from decimal to binary.
i'm almost done.

```
package binek;

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException;        
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Binek {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String cislo;  
         int vypocet=1;
         int zbytek=1;
         int a=0;

         BufferedReader in;
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         try{ cislo = in.readLine(); }
         catch(IOException e) {cislo="";} 
         int dec=Integer.valueOf(cislo); 
         int[] pole = new int[10];
         vypocet=dec/2;
         zbytek=dec%2;
         pole[0]=zbytek;

         while(vypocet!=0){
             a++;
             zbytek=vypocet%2;
             vypocet=vypocet/2;

             pole[a]=zbytek;
         }

         for (int i = 9; i < pole.length; --i)
         {
            System.out.print (pole[i]);
         } // here is the field with unnecessary zeros
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what does this code do?  And what does it need to do?

Comment: _i'm almost done_..Congrats!! :) Anything else?

Comment: I think OP clearly said *I need to remove the zeros* and *// here is the field with unnecessary zeros*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's the [***question***](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? Asking about your homework is fine here on SO (be sure to use the `homework` tag that Matzi added for you), but the question needs to be very targeted and specific to a given problem you're having.

Comment: i need to remove the zeros...for exam: input is 4...output is 0000000100 ,i need to remove first 7 zeros(i need to get only 100-binary) understand?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow user1477988. People, there is no need to moderate a question into oblivion if the user is willing to make some changes (within the first 26 minutes of asking no less).

Comment: @Ravinder: So he did.  But describing the problem by burying it as a comment in a big chunk of code is not "clear"!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is wrong: you are starting from the end of the array and checking that the array index is less than array length -- it's always less than that. So you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This is the corrected loop, with leading zeros removed:

```
boolean leadingZeros = true;
for (int i = pole.length; i > 0; i--) {
  if (leadingZeros && pole[i-1] == 0) continue; else leadingZeros = false;
  System.out.print(pole[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: (a note on SO rules: no need to thank verbally, but enable the large check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as _accepted_).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Integer.toBinaryString(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and convert method will be like this

```
public void convertToBinary(int decimal){
   System.out.println("Decimal value is " + decimal);
   System.out.println("Binary value is " + Integer.toBinaryString(decimal));
```

}

Comment: Since this is homework, this is probably not an option.

Comment: It can be one of the variants

Comment: If the objective of the homework is to implement the conversion algorithm, this would be like "copying the answer" :)

Comment: It can be used to check the correctness of the answer though, it seems to be the exact output required.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=polelength-1;i>=0;i--){

    if(pole[i] != 0) break;           
}

for(;i>=0;i--)
    System.out.print(pole[i]);
```

Comment: This corrects a mistake, but doesn't answer the question. OP wasn't even aware of this bug :)

Comment: `pole[pole.length-1]` will be the first thing to print regardless of its value, won't it? And why put `i--` inside the `for` body?

Comment: yea.....sorry abt that missed that he initialised the array with 10 elements